# How to preload lazy_static variables in Rust?

Tags: rust, lazy-static

I use Rust's lazy_static crate to assign a frequently used database object to a global variable but I do not want lazy loading. Is there a way to trigger lazy_static to preload the variable or is there a better way to achieve this? All the functions of the database are expensive and it seems to not be enough to assign a reference.

```rust
lazy_static! {
    static ref DB: DataBase = load_db();
}
 
/// this is too slow
#[allow(unused_must_use)] 
pub fn preload1() { DB.slow_function(); }

/// this does not cause lazy static to trigger
pub fn preload2() { let _ = &DB; }
```

Comment: Is `GRAPH` supposed to be `DB` or vice-versa?

Comment: Nit: Do not use `lazy_static`, use `once_cell`, its API is going to be integrated into std [and now it is even recommended by the compiler](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=f6798175c1c9b88d4a2d67b9ec91d68b).

Comment: @PitaJ: Yes, I forgot to change that from the real code to the example, thanks for noticing me! I fixed that.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman: I will do that! Interesting that the compiler recommends an external library, I have never seen that before in any language.

Comment: @KonradHöffner It was indeed doubted whether this should be implemented, but was now mainly because it is going to be part of the standard library.

Answer (score 1):

[`_` does not bind](https://medium.com/codechain/rust-underscore-does-not-bind-fec6a18115a8), so use a variable name (with leading underscore to avoid the lint):

```rust
use lazy_static::lazy_static; // 1.4.0

struct DataBase;
fn load_db() -> DataBase {
    println!("db loaded");
    DataBase
}

lazy_static! {
    static ref DB: DataBase = load_db();
}

fn main() {
    let _db: &DataBase = &*DB; // prints "db loaded"
}
```

[playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=19894f0b6d718c91e83d23886846a7d3)

Comment: The problem is not the `_`, it's the `&` that should be `&*`. Another solution is to type annotate as `&DataBase` to force a deref coercion, even with `_`.